# IIS_IUSRS Identity for a website

Tags: iis-7

I am using IIS7 to host an asp.net 2.0 site. However, whenever I browse it I get the error

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Now I realize that this is because the `IIS_IUSRS` does not have access to the web.config. My question is how can I grant access to `IIS_IUSRS`

When I look under Application Pools and check the Identity. It shows

```
ApplicationPoolIdentity(default), LocalService, LocalUser and Network Service
```

However, I cannot seem to find `IIS_IUSRS`

Where do I find it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[IIS_IUSRS](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis) is actually a Windows group so you won't find it under the application pools in IIS.

If you need to grant this group access, then this will need to be done via the file system, e.g. you could go to the folder where you have deployed your ASP.NET application and grant permissions to the group:

[image: Add IIS_IUSRS]

Comment: I added IIS_IUSRS . I now get the following error You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your deployment it is hard to troubleshoot with certainty, but perhaps the guidance [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942042) and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/38222/iis-7-5-windows-7-http-error-401-3-unauthorized) and [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1148826.aspx) could get you started. It seems to crop up quite regularly if you search around....

Comment: I had to add IUSR and IIS_IUSRS users and assign permissions for these roles. It then started working.